# Getting 400 BadRequest from Microsoft Graph "Current authenticated context is not valid for this request"

Tags: jquery, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I registred an app in azure AD and also set the correct permissions for the app. I have tested with adal and jquery to make the authorization towards microsoft graph, I get the token, but when trying to make a GET request i got the following errormsg 400

**"Current authenticated context is not valid for this request"**

i have followed the following tutorial and have not changed anything:

[Jquery and ADAL](http://julieturner.net/series/extending-sharepoint-with-adal-and-the-microsoft-graph-api/)

could it be localstorage that is the problem?

Comment: Can you share the complete error response body? It has request-id and timestamp needed to debug the error.

Comment: It is also helpful if you can parse the token from [here](https://jwt.io/) then show the value with us. And what's the exact request you were trying?

Comment: I have figured this out now. :) But is there anyone who knows how i can access groups that I am member of as a user with non admin permissions? Now I only get the data when logged in as a administrator, is there any good solution to this yet?